# Exercise on convex functions

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to approach this exercise: Let $f$ be a real valued convex function that satisfies:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$$

prove that it must be $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

I know the definition of convexity and limits however I don't know how to prove this formally.

Comment: If $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$, then $$\frac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{x_3 - x_2} \geqslant \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$$ for convex $f$.

Comment: Conceptual understanding of proofs is at least as important as the ability to follow or produce them mechanically. The answers given so far are all valid, but only vvnitram's gives a conceptual argument for why the result is true, and it assumes a little familiarity with convex functions.

Comment: Do you have a mental image of what convex functions look like? In particular, are you familiar with convex sets (the origin of the terminology)? Once you have a picture of the function $f$ in your head, the reason for the result you need to prove should be intuitively clear. Then you can formalize it using any of the equivalent arguments given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, then there exists an $x_0<0$, s.t. $f(x_0)<f(0)$. Denote 
\begin{equation}
 k := \frac{f(0)-f(x_0)}{0-x_0}>0.
\end{equation}
Now by convexity of $f$, we can show that for $x>0$,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\geq \frac{f(0)-f(x_0)}{0-x_0}=k,
\end{equation}
i.e., $f(x)\geq f(0)+kx\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Another hint: from $f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right) \leq  \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}$, if we take $x_1=x$ and $x_2=-x$ then we have $2f(0) \leq  f(x)+f(-x) \Rightarrow -f(x) + 2f(0) \leq  f(-x)$. Taking the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\left(-f(x) + 2f(0)\right) \leq  \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(-x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}f(y)$$
or
$$\left(-\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)\right) + 2f(0) \leq\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}f(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if this lim is $-\infty$, $f$ must have a max, an absurd.
If this lim is a real number $a$, the line $y=a$ is an asintota of $f$. Why this is an absurd?

Comment: The $\lim$ needs not exist, so you must first prove that it does in fact exist.