# Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \infty$ if $f$ is a convex function such that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = −\infty$

Tags: convex-analysis

I need to prove the theorem

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function such
>   that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = −\infty$. Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \infty$

I can see clearly why this must hold by doing a graph where $f(x)$ converges to a constant when $x\rightarrow\infty$. But I have no idea of how to do a formal proof of this.

Comment: The current statement is self-contradictory. Is there a typo?

Comment: sorry, the first limit is going to $-\infty$. made that edit now

Comment: Hint: convex functions always lie above their tangent lines, and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ forces some tangent line to have positive slope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the fact that since $\frac{1}{2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2}f(-x) \ge f(0)$ you have that $\frac{1}{2}f(x) \ge f(0)-\frac{1}{2}f(-x)$. Then $\lim f(x) \ge 2f(0)-f(-x) = +\infty$

Comment: It should be $f(x) + f(-x) \ge 2f(0)$ (but the question is a duplicate anyway, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2081099/42969).